# What does the /users endpoint look for when sorting on modified date?

Tags: app, api, users, api-v2.3

What does the /users endpoint look for when sorting on modified date?

For the /users endpoint in the Stack Exchange API v2.3, what does the `modified` filter in `sort` field look for?
It is unclear from the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).

1. Does modified date include any change triggered by system or user (change in user details or change in reputation by the system)?
2. Does it includes only the user made changes like details change or something?
3. Does it includes only the System triggered changes like changes in reputation, badge count etc?
4. Does it includes any changes in user profiles?

More precisely, I am interested to know whether `modified` date includes system triggered changes (reputation change, badge count etc) or not?

Comment: I have no idea. Right now, if you ask for the last modified users on this very site, you're the first entry (seems logical, you signed up today) and [this](https://stackapps.com/users/66244/kltr) is the second entry. That user hasn't been seen for quite a while and even with moderator tools I have no idea what happened to them today.

Comment: could you vote this up, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523098/what-does-modified-date-filter-in-user-end-point-consist-of)
so that its reputation get changed and it should appear by modified filter in top places. Currently it is on 10th places. It is for testing purpose

Comment: I'm pretty sure reputation modifications don't count towards this sorting option.

Comment: Without actual results, we can be assured of that. We need to test that first. See if you can vote that up , will update in answer

Comment: If it would, I would appear higher in the list...